# How can I fix the variable to an element property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a value to a style property of an object in HTML, but the variable changes to the new set value, instead of changing the value of the property:

```
var x = document.getElementById('box').style.height;
x = 20 + "px";
```

when I try this, x changes into a string "20px" instead of changing the value of the height.
x = 20; doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
document.getElementById('box').style.height = '20px';
```

Or

```
var element = document.getElementById('box');
element.style.height = '20px';
```